# get id of a cell in a table inside a div (JS and HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hi I have a php script that draws a table subject to certain conditions. When the table is drawn it is inside a div called ‘window’  and the table is called ‘visi’ I then want to use the code below to get the id’s of each cell in the table. I can get the class name no problem but get absolutely nothing from the id. Can anyone give me an idea of what i am doing wrong?. I have tried a similar peice of code on a table that is not inside a div and it works fine.  Any help would be great and I hope the code makes sense.

```
function confirm_allocate() {
var msg = ""   
var tab = document.getElementById('visi');
var r = tab.rows.length

for (i=0; i<r; i++){
cc = tab.rows.cells.length
         for (col=0; col<cc; col++){
            x=document.getElementById('visi').rows.cells;   

            iden = x[col].className
            ref =  x[col].id

            msg += "Class =" + iden + " ///    Id =" + ref +  "\r" 
         } 
} 
alert (msg ) 
}
```

If it helps this is the code to draw the table (but this is called using js/ ajax after getting the information for the table  )

```
<?php

$table = ""  ;
include '../database_sql/dbconnect.php' ;
include '../functions/job_details.php';
include '../functions/check_date.php';
include '../functions/stock_list.php' ; 
include '../functions/allocated_on_date.php' ; 

$jobdate = $_GET['jobdate'] ;
$jobnumber = $_GET['jobnumber'] ;
$jobname = $_GET['jobname'] ;

$screens = screens_per_job($jobnumber,$size) ;

$table =  "<h2 align= 'center' > $jobname (Job Number $jobnumber) : Screens required : $screens </h2>"  ;
$table .= "<table id='visi' width='480px'  align='center'  cellspacing='1'  cellpadding='1'   border='1' ><tr>"  ;

// get stock list from DB 
stock_list() ; 
$len = count( $stock);

$evresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event WHERE jobnumber = '$jobnumber' ")  ;
$event_row = mysql_fetch_array($evresult);

for ($counter = 0; $counter < $len; $counter++) {
      $item =  $stock[$counter] ;
      $items = $item . "s" ; 
      $booked_for_job = $event_row[$items] ;
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $item ")  ;
      allocated_on_date($jobdate) ; // function 

         if ($booked_for_job) {   
         $count =  1 ;
         $table .= "<td >$item<br> [$booked_for_job to Allocate] </td> " ;

               WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ;
               $booked_job = $screens[$item][$count]["job"] ;  // from the   allocated_on_date($jobdate)  function  
               $description = $row['trailer_id'];
               $class = $items ;
               $id_items = $items . $count ;
               $count ++ ;   

                        if ($booked_job == $jobnumber) {  // allocated to current job
                        $table .= "<td class='truckbox' > <div class='$class' id='$id_items' onClick='allocate(\"$booked_for_job\",\"$id_items\")'  > " ;
                        $table .= "$num </div>   </td>"  ;

                                 } ELSEIF ($booked_job === 0 ) {  // available to allocated 
                                 $class .= "g"   ;
                                    $table .= "<td class='truckbox' > <div class='$class' id='$id_items' onClick='allocate(\"$booked_for_job\",\"$id_items\")'  > " ;
                                 $table .= "$num </div>   </td>"  ;

                                                   } ELSE {    // allocated to ANOTHER job 
                                                   $class .= "a"   ;
                                                   $table .= "<td class='truckbox' > <div class='$class' id='$items' > " ;
                                                   $table .= "</td> "  ;
                                                   }

               } // while 

         $table .= "</tr>" ; 
         } ; // if
}; //for


$table .= "</table> " ;

$table .= "<table width='200px'  align='center'  cellspacing='12'  cellpadding='1'   ><tr>" ; // draw table buttons close and allocate
$table .= "</tr><tr>" ;
$table .= "<td class='truckbox' <div class='yesbutton' id='yes' onClick='confirm_allocate()' ; return false ;  >  ";
$table .= "<td class='truckbox' <div class='nobutton' id='no' onClick='hide()'   >  ";
$table .= "</tr></table> ";

echo $table ; // finally draw table   

include '../database_sql/dbclose.php' ;

?>
```

Comment: I think you need to take another stab at code highlighting. Make sure every line of code is indented by at least 4 spaces or 1 tab...

Comment: Is it possible to display a generated table? (HTML)

Comment: Robert, 

here is the link to the table 

http://www.abbeysoft.co.uk/adi/diary_booking/diary_view.php From there you need to click 'listings date range and make sure the range includes 2009-10-15, then click Pontefract Racecourse in orange this will display the table. 

If you inspect the elements you can clearly see there is a unique ID for each cell 

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `id` attributes on the table cells (`td` elements) that are being generated. So `ref` is just going to be blank or undefined.

If that's not the problem then it could be the `.rows.cells`. Try `.getElementsByTagName('td')` instead. I think that line should be outside the loop, since it's not changing on each iteration.

Also, the latter part of your HTML is wrong - you don't close the `td` tag. Instead of `<td class='truckbox' <div class...` it should be `<td class='truckbox'><div class...`

Comment: I appologise DG ! The ID is inside the div element. once I moved it to the TD everything worked. 
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to access the array elements:

```
...
for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
  var row = tab.rows[i];
  var cc = row.cells.length;

  for (col=0; col<cc; col++){
    var x = row.cells[col];
...
```

Comment: Thanks , but either your way or my way does not work , cheers

Comment: Neither your <table> nor the <td> elements seem to have an id attribute on the example page you linked.